# Graph manipulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, graph-algorithm

Does there exist a graph manipulation library in JavaScript?
**Not a visualization**, but algorithms, such as search for shortest path, Hamiltonian path, cut edges, cycle detection, and generation of a spanning tree.

Comment: There are lots - search on NPM

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of algorithms in Cytoscape.js:

http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/algorithms

```
eles.breadthFirstSearch()
eles.depthFirstSearch()
eles.dijkstra()
eles.aStar()
eles.floydWarshall()
eles.bellmanFord()
eles.kruskal()
eles.kargerStein()
eles.pageRank()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close! Still looking for cut edges.